# Opensuse Kernel panic

Tags: kernel, opensuse

kernel update '**4.1.27-27.1**' of **opensuse leap 42.1** is suffering from kernel panic. I am unable to run large programs like android studio. The pc freezes and caps Lock blinks. It happens also when laptop lid is closed. So how can I degrade the the Kernel to the stock one '**4.1.12-1**' .

Answer (score 0):

I am using openSuse 13.1, not Leap (yet...?), so I may be completely off.

For 13.1 I'd say

1. go to the software manager, YaST
2. search for "kernel"
3. select yours ("kernel-desktop" here)
4. see what versions are available and choose to install / downgrade to one of them
5. reboot

[image: YaST screenshot with kernel versions]

Again, I do not know Leap, also I never downgraded the kernel, so... use with care. (backups are your friends)

Note that [openSuse's forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/index.php) is quite friendly too.

(edit: image)

Comment: can I downgrade from yast

Comment: @PrafuldevVR: The option to downgrade is there (see the image I added to the reply above). I have downgraded other applications once in a while using YaST, yet never the kernel, but if it is there it should be reasonably safe to try. (again: backup!)